# how to open a lightning component from vf page by using window.open()?

Tags: visualforce, lightning-aura-components

I am trying to open my lightning component from a vf page on click of button by using window.open(), is it possible to do. or please suggest me any work around for this.

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[I have answered this previously](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/223580/718), but essentially with the new `lightning:isUrlAddressable` interface, it's possible to link directly to a component without the app container method.

So you can do:

*MyComponent*

```
<aura:component implements="lightning:isUrlAddressable">
.....
</aura:component>
```

*VF Page JS*

```
window.open(https://<domain>.lightning.force.com/lightning/cmp/c__MyComponent);
```

Comment: Nice. I must have missed that in the release notes.